# Subtract value from previous row value if it is greater than the max value

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

Im using Postgresql & Sequelize. I have to find the consumption from the reading table.  Currently, I have the query to subtract the value from the previous row. But the problem was If the value is less than the previous value means I have to ignore the row and need to wait for the greater value to make the calculation.

Current Query

```
select "readingValue",
       "readingValue" - coalesce(lag("readingValue") over (order by "id")) as consumption
from public."EnergyReadingTbl";
```

Example Record & Current Output

```
id      readingValue        consumption

65479   "35.8706703186035"  "3.1444168090820"
65480   "39.0491638183594"  "3.1784934997559"
65481   "42.1287002563477"  "3.0795364379883"
65482   "2.38636064529419"  "-39.74233961105351"
65483   "5.91744041442871"  "3.53107976913452"
65484   "9.59204387664795"  "3.67460346221924"
65485   "14.3925561904907"  "4.80051231384275"
65486   "19.4217891693115"  "5.0292329788208"
65487   "24.2393398284912"  "4.8175506591797"
65488   "29.2515335083008"  "5.0121936798096"
65489   "34.2519302368164"  "5.0003967285156"
65490   "38.6513633728027"  "4.3994331359863"
65491   "43.7513643778087"  "5.1000010050060"
```

In this picture, the last max value was 42.1287002563477. I have to wait until to get the greater value than 42.1287002563477 to make the calculation like the next greater value - 42.1287002563477. In this, 43.7513643778087 - 42.1287002563477.

Expected Output

```
id      readingValue        consumption

65479   "35.8706703186035"  "3.1444168090820"
65480   "39.0491638183594"  "3.1784934997559"
65481   "42.1287002563477"  "3.0795364379883"
65482   "2.38636064529419"  "0"
65483   "5.91744041442871"  "0"
65484   "9.59204387664795"  "0"
65485   "14.3925561904907"  "0"
65486   "19.4217891693115"  "0"
65487   "24.2393398284912"  "0"
65488   "29.2515335083008"  "0"
65489   "34.2519302368164"  "0"
65490   "38.6513633728027"  "0"
65491   "43.7513643778087"  "1.1226641214710"
```

Is there any chance to resolve this issue in the query?

Comment: Please add some sample data (as text not as image) and expected output

Comment: @S-Man - Updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING` to limit the frame of the window function, so you can substract the `MAX` up to the current row with the `MAX` value of the rows up to but excluding the current row:

```
SELECT readingValue,
       MAX(readingValue) OVER (ORDER BY id) - MAX(readingValue) OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
FROM e;

┌──────────────────┬─────────────────┐
│   readingvalue   │    ?column?     │
├──────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ 35.8706703186035 │          (null) │
│ 39.0491638183594 │ 3.1784934997559 │
│ 42.1287002563477 │ 3.0795364379883 │
│ 2.38636064529419 │               0 │
│ 5.91744041442871 │               0 │
│ 9.59204387664795 │               0 │
│ 14.3925561904907 │               0 │
│ 19.4217891693115 │               0 │
│ 24.2393398284912 │               0 │
│ 29.2515335083008 │               0 │
│ 34.2519302368164 │               0 │
│ 38.6513633728027 │               0 │
│ 43.7513643778087 │  1.622664121461 │
└──────────────────┴─────────────────┘
(13 rows)

Time: 0,430 ms
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got the Solution as expected

Comment: This is a really great one!